# Origen de la expresión "poner mirando a Cuenca"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa, vulgaridades

Buscando el origen de la expresión *poner mirando a Cuenca* me he encontrado con un posible origen en la web, que hace referencia a una versión original *poner mirando a la Meca*:

> Si pensamos en la postura que usan los musulmanes para rezar, la cosa empieza a cuadrar. Ellos rezan mirando al Este, lugar donde está La Meca. Si te sitúas en Madrid y trazas una línea recta hasta la principal ciudad de la región del Hiyaz, Cuenca es la primera población en ese recorrido.
>
> <sub>[Fuente: Quo](http://www.quo.es/ser-humano/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-te-voy-a-poner-mirando-a-cuenca)</sub>

Quizá es inventada (o son ese tipo de bulo que la gente toma por auténtico en Internet por no prestar atención a las fuentes, o es directamente un *fake* creado para echarse unas risas).

¿Sabe alguien cuál es el origen de la expresión "poner mirando a Cuenca"?

Comment: No encuentro ninguna referencia a la expresión ni en el CORDE, ni en el CREA, ni en el CORPES XII, ni en la hemeroteca. Siempre la he tenido como una expresión de reciente cuño, por lo que me cuesta creer la primera historia. En cambio la segunda la acabo de verificar usando Google Maps: la línea más corta sobre la superficie terrestre entre Madrid y Yidda (la ciudad principal de la región del Hiyaz), pasa exactamente por encima de Cuenca.

Comment: La primera "versión" a que haces referencia no es tal, y la página no se llama *Etimologías* sino *Emitologías*. Es una página que publica falsas etimologías con fines humorísticos. Hay quien está enfadado con ellos porque considera que esta intención humorística no está tan clara y llama a error.

Comment: Diego, de acuerdo con lo comentado por @Gorpik he quitado esa parte de Emitologías, pues ese sitio es algo así como una bola que se hizo demasiado grande y nos ha llevado a diferentes equívocos en este sitio :D

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' tanto que terminamos añadiéndolo como uno de los [comentarios útiles para el sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3171/5481). Gracias por el edit.

Answer (score 4):

Según lo que he oído a un guía turístico en la propia Cuenca, data de un *sketch* del dúo humorístico Cruz y Raya, del año 2004. El dúo era muy popular en España en esa época y la expresión habría hecho fortuna al aparecer en su programa de televisión.

No tengo buenas referencias que justifiquen esta versión, pero, de 50200 resultados que me da Google para la expresión "mirando a Cuenca", no hay uno solo anterior a 2004 (salvo dos o tres de una web turística que la usa con el sentido literal). En 2004 empiezan a aparecer resultados con el sentido figurado que le damos hoy día.

Answer (score 1):

El significado:

> La expresión “Poner mirando pa’ Cuenca” se utiliza frecuentemente para
>   hacer una clara referencia a la posición sexual conocida comúnmente
>   como ‘postura del perro’ (o más formalmente ‘coito a tergo’) y por
>   analogía la misma postura en la que se colocan los musulmanes a la
>   hora de orar.

El origen:

> Si trazásemos una línea recta desde Madrid hacia La Meca (tal y como
>   aparece en la imagen del mapa que ilustra este post) podremos observar
>   que Cuenca está situada en la misma trayectoria, siendo la primera
>   población/provincia en ese recorrido en línea recta saliendo desde la
>   capital de España en dirección a la ciudad islámica.
>
> Y es más que posible que sea esta la razón por la que se cambió la
>   expresión, que en su origen era “Poner mirando a La Meca”, por la
>   referencia de Cuenca con la intención de darle un sentido más castizo
>   y cañí a un modismo que se utiliza, tal y como he especificado, como
>   clara alusión a la postura y orientación en la que se colocan los
>   musulmanes para realizar sus oraciones y su parecido a la mencionada
>   postura sexual.

Fuente: https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-poner-mirando-a-cuenca/

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta,en el link que he adjuntado está la información que se pregunta. Gracias!